# Flutter web app shows blank screen when publishing it

Tags: flutter

I am working on a Flutter project.

I need to create a web app from the project.

The web app is launched at https://appcapenergy.com/web

Today I have made an update from the project, I have published the iOS app and the Android app to the stores, Apple App Store and Google Play.

Now I have build the web app, but it is not working.

Launching the web app locally or in the server it only shows a blank screen.

Here you have the browser inspection Console log:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('http://localhost:61121/') with script ('http://localhost:61121/firebase-messaging-sw.js'): A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script.
main.dart.js:72 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'removeChild')
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (main.dart.js:72:22)
    at client.js:24535:40
    at _wrapJsFunctionForAsync_closure.$protected (client.js:3471:15)
    at _wrapJsFunctionForAsync_closure.call$2 (client.js:11541:12)
    at _awaitOnObject_closure.call$1 (client.js:11529:32)
    at StaticClosure._rootRunUnary (client.js:3833:18)
    at _CustomZone.runUnary$2$2 (client.js:12941:39)
    at _Future__propagateToListeners_handleValueCallback.call$0 (client.js:11973:51)
    at Object._Future__propagateToListeners (client.js:3613:93)
    at _Future._completeWithValue$1 (client.js:11799:9)
    at _AsyncAwaitCompleter.complete$1 (client.js:11512:14)
    at Object._asyncReturn (client.js:3443:17)
    at client.js:8734:24
    at _wrapJsFunctionForAsync_closure.$protected (client.js:3471:15)
    at _wrapJsFunctionForAsync_closure.call$2 (client.js:11541:12)
    at _awaitOnObject_closure.call$1 (client.js:11529:32)
    at StaticClosure._rootRunUnary (client.js:3833:18)
    at _CustomZone.runUnary$2$2 (client.js:12941:39)
    at _Future__propagateToListeners_handleValueCallback.call$0 (client.js:11973:51)
    at Object._Future__propagateToListeners (client.js:3613:93)
    at _Future._completeWithValue$1 (client.js:11799:9)
    at _AsyncAwaitCompleter.complete$1 (client.js:11512:14)
    at Object._asyncReturn (client.js:3443:17)
    at client.js:25007:24
    at _wrapJsFunctionForAsync_closure.$protected (client.js:3471:15)
    at _wrapJsFunctionForAsync_closure.call$2 (client.js:11541:12)
    at _awaitOnObject_closure.call$1 (client.js:11529:32)
    at StaticClosure._rootRunUnary (client.js:3833:18)
    at _CustomZone.runUnary$2$2 (client.js:12941:39)
    at _Future__propagateToListeners_handleValueCallback.call$0 (client.js:11973:51)
    at Object._Future__propagateToListeners (client.js:3613:93)
    at _Future._completeWithValue$1 (client.js:11799:9)
    at _AsyncAwaitCompleter.complete$1 (client.js:11512:14)
    at Object._asyncReturn (client.js:3443:17)
    at client.js:24984:24
    at _wrapJsFunctionForAsync_closure.$protected (client.js:3471:15)
    at _wrapJsFunctionForAsync_closure.call$2 (client.js:11541:12)
    at _awaitOnObject_closure.call$1 (client.js:11529:32)
    at StaticClosure._rootRunUnary (client.js:3833:18)
    at _CustomZone.runUnary$2$2 (client.js:12941:39)
    at _Future__propagateToListeners_handleValueCallback.call$0 (client.js:11973:51)
    at Object._Future__propagateToListeners (client.js:3613:93)
    at _Future._completeWithValue$1 (client.js:11799:9)
    at _Future__asyncCompleteWithValue_closure.call$0 (client.js:11901:18)
    at StaticClosure._rootRun (client.js:3818:16)
    at _CustomZone.run$1$1 (client.js:12933:39)
    at _CustomZone.runGuarded$1 (client.js:12876:14)
    at _CustomZone_bindCallbackGuarded_closure.call$0 (client.js:13071:25)
    at Object._microtaskLoop (client.js:3677:24)
    at StaticClosure._startMicrotaskLoop (client.js:3683:11)
    at _AsyncRun__initializeScheduleImmediate_internalCallback.call$1 (client.js:11417:9)
    at invokeClosure (client.js:1277:26)
    at MutationObserver.<anonymous> (client.js:1296:18)
​ This app is linked to the debug service: ws://127.0.0.1:61185/AiCArEXaM00=/ws
js_primitives.dart:30 Flutter Web Bootstrap: Programmatic
errors.dart:266 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Unsupported operation: Platform._operatingSystem
    at Object.throw_ [as throw] (errors.dart:266:49)
    at _Platform._operatingSystem (io_patch.dart:244:5)
    at get operatingSystem [as operatingSystem] (platform_impl.dart:56:40)
    at get _operatingSystem (platform.dart:64:45)
    at desc.get [as _operatingSystem] (operations.dart:839:8)
    at get isIOS (platform.dart:153:47)
    at desc.get [as isIOS] (operations.dart:839:8)
    at MethodChannelStripeFactory.create (method_channel_stripe.dart:479:33)
    at get _instance (stripe_platform_interface.dart:12:72)
    at desc.get [as _instance] (operations.dart:839:8)
    at get instance [as instance] (stripe_platform_interface.dart:17:41)
    at get _platform [as _platform] (stripe.dart:535:35)
    at stripe.Stripe.__.markNeedsSettings (stripe.dart:542:20)
    at set publishableKey [as publishableKey] (stripe.dart:24:14)
    at main$ (main.dart:38:10)
    at main$.next (<anonymous>)
    at runBody (async_patch.dart:84:54)
    at Object._async [as async] (async_patch.dart:123:5)
    at main$ (main.dart:34:5)
    at web_entrypoint.dart:24:31
    at Object._checkAndCall (operations.dart:334:14)
    at Object.dcall (operations.dart:339:39)
    at initialization.dart:77:15
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at async_patch.dart:45:50
    at _RootZone.runUnary (zone.dart:1653:54)
    at _FutureListener.thenAwait.handleValue (future_impl.dart:147:18)
    at handleValueCallback (future_impl.dart:766:44)
    at _Future._propagateToListeners (future_impl.dart:795:13)
    at [_completeWithValue] (future_impl.dart:566:5)
    at async._AsyncCallbackEntry.new.callback (future_impl.dart:639:7)
    at Object._microtaskLoop (schedule_microtask.dart:40:11)
    at _startMicrotaskLoop (schedule_microtask.dart:49:5)
    at async_patch.dart:166:15
throw_ @ errors.dart:266
_operatingSystem @ io_patch.dart:244
get operatingSystem @ platform_impl.dart:56
get _operatingSystem @ platform.dart:64
desc.get @ operations.dart:839
get isIOS @ platform.dart:153
desc.get @ operations.dart:839
create @ method_channel_stripe.dart:479
get _instance @ stripe_platform_interface.dart:12
desc.get @ operations.dart:839
get instance @ stripe_platform_interface.dart:17
get _platform @ stripe.dart:535
markNeedsSettings @ stripe.dart:542
set publishableKey @ stripe.dart:24
main$ @ main.dart:38
runBody @ async_patch.dart:84
_async @ async_patch.dart:123
main$ @ main.dart:34
(anonymous) @ web_entrypoint.dart:24
_checkAndCall @ operations.dart:334
dcall @ operations.dart:339
(anonymous) @ initialization.dart:77
(anonymous) @ async_patch.dart:45
runUnary @ zone.dart:1653
handleValue @ future_impl.dart:147
handleValueCallback @ future_impl.dart:766
_propagateToListeners @ future_impl.dart:795
[_completeWithValue] @ future_impl.dart:566
(anonymous) @ future_impl.dart:639
_microtaskLoop @ schedule_microtask.dart:40
_startMicrotaskLoop @ schedule_microtask.dart:49
(anonymous) @ async_patch.dart:166
Promise.then (async)
_scheduleImmediateWithPromise @ async_patch.dart:164
_scheduleImmediate @ async_patch.dart:136
_scheduleAsyncCallback @ schedule_microtask.dart:69
_rootScheduleMicrotask @ zone.dart:1458
scheduleMicrotask @ zone.dart:1673
[_asyncCompleteWithValue] @ future_impl.dart:638
[_asyncComplete] @ future_impl.dart:598
runBody @ async_patch.dart:108
_async @ async_patch.dart:123
initializeEngineUi @ initialization.dart:224
(anonymous) @ initialization.dart:75
runBody @ async_patch.dart:84
_async @ async_patch.dart:123
(anonymous) @ initialization.dart:71
_checkAndCall @ operations.dart:334
callMethod @ operations.dart:398
dsend @ operations.dart:402
(anonymous) @ app_bootstrap.dart:72
runBody @ async_patch.dart:84
_async @ async_patch.dart:123
(anonymous) @ app_bootstrap.dart:70
_checkAndCall @ operations.dart:334
dcall @ operations.dart:339
ret @ js_patch.dart:413
(anonymous) @ app_bootstrap.dart:68
_checkAndCall @ operations.dart:334
dcall @ operations.dart:339
ret @ js_patch.dart:413
(anonymous) @ web:53
```

I need your help to try to solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

Please do this!

I run this in the console of my navigator (Chrome), and no error message anymore :

```
navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistrations().then(function(registrations) { for(let registration of registrations) { registration.unregister() } })
```

and check this link
[https://www.fluttercampus.com/guide/163/how-to-fix-blank-white-page-from-hosted-flutter-web-app/#:~:text=html%20with%20code%20editor%2C%20you,attribute%20to%20solve%20this%20problem](https://www.fluttercampus.com/guide/163/how-to-fix-blank-white-page-from-hosted-flutter-web-app/#:%7E:text=html%20with%20code%20editor%2C%20you,attribute%20to%20solve%20this%20problem)

Comment: Great, but how to avoid the issue for the rest of the app users?

Comment: Please check my answer again its edited

Comment: Thank you, but I guess it is not an issue about that part of the index.html file. The error is talking about a 404 error looking for file firebase-messaging-ws.js, which is included in the folder

Comment: Slightly unreleated but @mvasco I took a look at the page source and noticed an api key is there, would highly recommend modifying code to hide this to avoid it being abused.

Comment: @Edtimer, it is a test key, but thank you